# How do I read from a file and put it into a list as an integer? Python

Tags: python, list, file

This is what I have

```
file = open("numberlist.txt")
list = []
for line in file:
      line = line.strip()
      list.append(line)
```

I would line to convert each line into an integer in the for line in file: How do I do this?

Optional: And If I have non numerical character in `numberlist.txt`? how can I test that and have to program tell me the file is not OK?

Comment: Side note: Don't call your list `list`. If you do that, you can't access the actual `list` type anymore.

Comment: if you open a file with `variable = open()` then don't forget to also close it via `variable.close()`

Answer (score 3):

If you have one digit in each line you can directly use a [file-object](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) and `map` function :

```
with open("numberlist.txt") as f:
     num_list=map(int,f)
```

Notes : never use of python built-in names as your variable names and also open your file with `with` statement.

> The with statement is used to wrap the execution of a block with methods defined by a context manager.

Read more about the `with` statement and its usage advantage. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html

But if you may have non numerical characters in your file based on whats your file look like you can use some recipes like `exception-handling` that it can be done with `try-except` statement.

So if we suppose you have one word (contains digit or character) in each line you can do

```
num_list=[]
with open("numberlist.txt") as f:

  for line in f:
     try :
       num_list.append(int(line))
     except:
       continue #or other stuffs
```

*Note* that this can have a lot of scenarios and based on your code you can use various approaches!

Comment: Why add `f.readlines()` instead of just his original `f`? It doesn't add anything except to make the code longer, slower, and wasteful of memory.

Comment: @abarnert Sure, as i remember i have answered a lot of questions that i recommended using `file-object` instead of read lines :). So i know all the reasons it just was a strange forgotten! thanks a lot for reminding!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `int` constructor or type-caster if you will, to convert string to integer. it throws a `ValueError` if the conversion is not possible.

```
int_value = int(strvalue)
```

a good way to do the same operation on all elements in a list in python is to use the `map` function. do a `help(map)` in the interpreter to see how it works

```
# assuming that the file exists
file = open("numberlist.txt")
my_list = []
for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        list.append(line)
try:
    list_of_ints = map(int, my_list)
except ValueError:
    print("invalid file")
```

to check if the list is proper, put the operation in a try-except block.

you can do all of this in a couple of lines by using the `with` statement

```
with open("numbers.txt") as file_object:
    try:
        list_of_ints = map(int, (l.strip() for l in file_object))
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid file")
```

here i am using file_object as an iterable (it gives all the lines in the file). and using the generator syntax to create another iterable on which to apply the map function

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("numberlist.txt",'r')
l = []

for line in file:
    line = line.split()
    try:
        l.append(int(line[0]))
    except:
        continue
```