# reading list of integers from input line in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, int

I am using `Python 2.7.6`. I have a Python program snippet that is giving me a list of strings, but I need to have list of integers. For example, the program is as below:

```
L = []
nums = raw_input("")
L = nums.split()
print L
```

The output is:

```
>>> 
2 3 4
['2', '3', '4']
>>>
```

But I need to have a list of integers as: `[2, 3, 4]` and not as `['2', '3', '4']`. How can I do that? Please suggest.
Similar Question/Ans is here: [How do I read from a file and put it into a list as an integer? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998873/how-do-i-read-from-a-file-and-put-it-into-a-list-as-an-integer-python)
But, the solution seems to expect one digit in each line, but here, I have multiple digits in same line as input.

Comment: Similar Question/Ans is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998873/how-do-i-read-from-a-file-and-put-it-into-a-list-as-an-integer-python . But, the solution seems to expect one digit in each line, but here, I have multiple digits in same line as input.

Comment: You can use `map` to map the strings to int - `map(int,raw_input().split())`