# I am having trouble saving in a list integers taken from a file

Tags: python, list

the exercise ask us to check whether the numbers contained in a file are a magic square or not.

first of all I am triyng to create a list with all the values that I will then transform into a matrix and then check `if sum of first row == sum first column == sum of diagonal`.

My problem is way more easy than the exercise:

List L is the one I will modify into a matrix but I'd like to have it clean, I succeeded in having it as `L=[7,1,2,1,1,4,"\n" and so on]` but I am trying to save **1,2 as 12 and 1,4 as 14.**

I tried to do it as the following but I get a str index out of range, that seems weird as I tried in every way to keep the `indexes < than len-1`. could you kindly have a look?

I know there may be other ways to implement the exercise, but in this moment I am interested in how edit list L into LI=[7, 12, 1, 14, "\n", 2, 13, 8, 11, "\n", 16, 3, 10, 5, "\n", 9, 6, 15, 4]

```
L=['7', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '4', '\n', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '8', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', '\n', '1', '6', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '5', '\n', '9', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '6', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '5', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '4']
    LI=[ ]
    j=len(L)-1
    for i in range(0,j):
        for el in L:
            if el[i]!=" " and el[i+1]!=" ":
                LI.append(el[i]*10+el[i+1])
            elif el!=" ":
                LI.append(el)
    print(LI)
```

**Error -:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-164-73294659fea7> in <module>
          4 for i in range(0,j):
          5     for el in L:
    ----> 6         if el[i]!=" " and el[i+1]!=" ":
          7                 L.append(el[i]*10+el[i+1])
          8         elif el!=" ":
          IndexError: string index out of range
***
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please fix the formatting of your code so we can cut & paste it.
Also include the full text of your error message: include the trace-back.
Finally, put in a couple of `print` statements to trace the flow and data values, so you can see where the program deviates from your expectations.

Comment: Hi Prune, thanks for your advice, I am new on here. I tried to fix it, I hope it is acceptable

Comment: @Beatrice Welcome to stack overflow, Check the solution I wrote below if its what your looking for please mark it as an answer, otherwise comment what exactly you want to do because I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: The problem is even before your posted code.  You should read in your numbers as separate integers, *not* as a list of individual characters.  Search for "Python input list of integers" for how to do this.

Comment: Here is the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998873/how-do-i-read-from-a-file-and-put-it-into-a-list-as-an-integer-python) of your underlying problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also managed to solve it in another way, if you're interested here it is my code:

```
def Magic(file):
    with open("macigsquare.txt") as f:
        mat=[[int(x) for x in lines.split()] for lines in f] #opening my file
        cols=[] #initialiting lists to save sum of rows, sum of cols, sum of diagonal
        rows=[]
        diag=[]
        mat1 = [x for x in mat if x != []] #getting rid of empty lists in my matrix
        n=len(mat1)          #defining n as the length of my matrix
        for j in range(len(mat1[0])):
            r=0      #initialising variables for the sum of each row and diagonal
            d=0
            for i in range (len(mat1)):
                r+=mat1[i][j]     #doing the sum of each row and sum of diagonal
                d+=mat1[i][i]
            cols.append(sum(mat1[i])) #appending the sum of columns
            diag.append(d)   #appending the sum of diagonal
            rows.append(r)   #appending the sum of rows 
            continue
    return sum(cols)==sum(rows) and sum(rows)==sum(diag) and sum(diag)==sum(cols)  #now the result checks if the sum of the three variables is the same, meaning it is a magic square.
```

The content of my file was:

```
 7    12    1    14
2    13    8    11
 16    3    10    5
 9    6    15    4
```

Comment: Please elaborate a little more on why your solution is working (prevents downvoting or deletion via review "low quality". (End of Review).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array of characters to represent the 'Magic Square' matrix you can represent it directly in code using an array of an array of integers which is a lot easier and straightforward.
Here is the code you need, written in Python, to solve the 'Magic Square' problem. The function *MagicSquare* take *NxN* matrix representing the square (in my code its the *arr* argument) and it's dimension *n* and return a *boolean* *True* if its magic square *False* otherwise.

**The General Algorithm:**

```
def CheckRowsColums(arr, n, s):
    for i in range(0, n):
        row_sum = 0
        col_sum = 0
        for j in range(0, n):
            row_sum += arr[i][j]
            col_sum += arr[j][i]
        if (s != row_sum or s != col_sum):
            return False
    return True

def CheckDiagonals(arr, n, s):
    diag_sum = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        diag_sum += arr[i][i]
    if (s != diag_sum):
            return False
    return True

def MagicSquare(arr, n):
    s = n * (n**2 + 1) / 2
    return CheckRowsColums(arr, n, s) and CheckDiagonals(arr, n, s)

L = [
        [9, 3, 22, 16, 15], 
        [2, 21, 20, 14, 8], 
        [25, 19, 13, 7, 1], 
        [18, 12, 6, 5, 24], 
        [11, 10, 4, 23, 17]
    ]
print(MagicSquare(L, 5))
```

The algorithm above have the complexity of O(n*n) which is quadratic.
**EDIT :** 
After clarifying your question I understand that your reading values from a file that represents the matrix.
Assuming the file format representing the matrix is like this :

```
9 3 22 16 15
2 21 20 14 8
25 19 13 7 1
18 12 6 5 24
11 10 4 23 17
```

Where each *line* represents a *row* of our square matrix.

You can read the file and supply it's values to the function defined above like this :

```
def Solve(file):
    with open(file) as f: # reading from file each line represents a row of our matrix
        matrix = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f] # matrix is what you need here
        return MagicSquare(matrix, len(matrix))

fn = input("Enter the filename that represents the square matrix : ")
if Solve(fn):
    print("Magic square !")
else:
    print("It's not a magic square :(")
```

The program will ask for the file name, after writing the file name and pressing enter it will process the file and print the results.
**Please Note:** That This approach is easier than reading the file character by character. Since python have built-in function to read integers from an input directly you have to make use of it otherwise your code will be over complicated if you decide to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hi Omarito, thanks for your solution, that is ok for a generic problem but unfortunately I have not a matrix but just a file with integers separated by spaces so I was copying them into an array to easily solve the problem in a way similar to yours.

Comment: Can you show me an example of such a file ? Whats the format of the text? Do you know the size of the matrix N ? Please edit your question to contain these informations so i can edit my solution accordingly.

Comment: my question is: how to transform the list L into the list LI=[7, 12, 1, 14, "\n", 2, 13, 8, 11, "\n", 16, 3, 10, 5, "\n", 9, 6, 15, 4]?

Comment: @Beatrice I edited my solution, now it should solve the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = ['7', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',
     '1', '4', '\n', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '8', ' ',
     ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', '\n', '1', '6', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '3', ' ', ' ', ' ',
     ' ', '1', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '5', '\n', '9', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '6', ' ',
     ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '5', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '4']
```

We combine the whole list to a string and then split it at the spaces.

```
data = ''.join(L)
print(data)
data = data.split(' ')
print(data)
```

The result will look like this:

```
7    12    1    14
2    13    8    11
16    3    10    5
9    6    15    4

['7', '', '', '', '12', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '14\n2', '', '', '', '13', '',
 '', '', '8', '', '', '', '11\n16', '', '', '', '3', '', '', '', '10', '', '', '',
 '5\n9', '', '', '', '6', '', '', '', '15', '', '', '', '4']
```

Looks like we have to seperate the `'\n'`. Let's add spaces around the newline character before splitting it.

```
data = ''.join(L).replace('\n', ' \n ')
data = data.split(' ')
print(data)
```

The result looks like this

```
['7', '', '', '', '12', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '14', '\n', '2', '', '', '',
 '13', '', '', '', '8', '', '', '', '11', '\n', '16', '', '', '', '3', '', '', '',
 '10', '', '', '', '5', '\n', '9', '', '', '', '6', '', '', '', '15', '', '', '',
 '4']
```

Now we construct a new list by looping over this intermediate result. If we encounter a `''` we'll ignore it, a `'\n'` will be taken as it is and everything else will be converted to an integer.

```
result = []
for value in data:
    if value != '':
        value = value if value == '\n' else int(value)
        result.append(value)
print(result)
```

Now you'll get the desired result.

```
[7, 12, 1, 14, '\n', 2, 13, 8, 11, '\n', 16, 3, 10, 5, '\n', 9, 6, 15, 4]
```

With a list comprehension the last part can be written as a one-liner.

```
result = [value if value == '\n' else int(value) for value in data if value]
```

We could even throw everything together.

```
result = [value if value == '\n' else int(value) for value in ''.join(L).replace('\n', ' \n ').split(' ') if value]
```

Comment: thanks for responding to my original question! @matthias